# Can't change content_type from application/octet-stream to application/json in RabbitMQ sink

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a simple RabbitMQ source and sink. I'm publishing a message to the source queue with the following properties:

```
content_type -> application/json
```

and a JSON payload:

```
{
  "userId": 2,
  "customerId": 1,
}
```

The RabbitMQ sink gets the message with `application/octet-stream` instead of JSON.

I tried to start the application with the following properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json
```

but it didn't help.

Stream definition:

```
stream_1=rabbitSource: rabbit --queues=queue1 --password=p --host=h --username=u | sink: rabbit --exchange=ex --routing-key=rk --converter-bean-name=jsonConverter --password=p --host=h --username=u
```

How can I set the content type to be `application/json`? The [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) doesn't seem to have the answer.

Release versions:

- spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.0.1.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.0.0.RELEASE

Update:

As suggested in the answers by @SabbyAnandan, I'm now running:

```
dataflow:>stream create --name test123 --definition "rabbitSource: rabbit --queues=queue --password=p --host=rmq --username=u --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType='application/json' | sink: rabbit --exchange=ex --routing-key=rk --converter-bean-name=jsonConverter --password=p --host=rmq --username=p"
Created new stream 'test123123'

dataflow:>stream deploy --name test123 --properties "app.rabbit.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType='application/json'"
Deployment request has been sent for stream 'test123'
```

But the `content_type` is still the same.

Comment: Hi. When describing problems with the shipped applications, it'd be helpful if you can also list the versions in use. Could you edit the post with the versions?

Comment: @SabbyAnandan Sure, will edit. Here's a [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3143) to the issue I opened on GitHub

Comment: Please update the versions of the app in use. This is an app-specific discussion as opposed to SCDF. The content-type negotiation has evolved significantly in the recent releases of Spring Cloud Stream and the corresponding releases of the apps that we ship, so let's start with the versions.

Comment: @SabbyAnandan I'm using the most recent versions. If I understood you correctly, I'm getting the apps from [here](http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor/Einstein.SR2/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor-Einstein.SR2.stream-apps-rabbit-maven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maroun, As discussed, here are some of the options.

1. Rabbit sink receives data as `byte[]` always. You can force it to use a json converter by providing a configuration(`--rabbit.converterBeanName=jsonConverter`). But that is by default uses a Base64 encoder and the resultant text will be Base64 encoded. Then in the custom app where it receives data from the exchange where sink is publishing to, you need to provide a custom converter that property decodes using a Base64 decoder.
2. The other option you have is to patch the Rabbit sink to fit your needs. Clone the [Rabbit app starter repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/rabbit) and then provide a `PassthroughConverter` that simply passes the incoming `byte[]` downstream. You need to somehow change the content type on the Message header as well (to `application/json`). Then the normal `Jackson` converter will work on the custom application side as the `byte[]` is not Base64 encoded in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time, I highly appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

The default content-type set in the header for the Rabbit-source is: [`content-type: application/x-java-serialized-object`](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/rabbit/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-rabbit/README.adoc#headers-1).

You can override that behavior by passing:

1) `--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType='application/json'` as an inline property to the Rabbit-source.

2) While deploying the stream, you can override the application-specific property via `--properties="app.rabbit.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType='application/json'`.

Once deployed, you can confirm whether or not the property is overridden by going to the application-specific `http://<APP-HOST>:<APP-PORT?/actuator/configprops` endpoint.

To troubleshoot all this, you can run the apps standalone (i.e., `java -jar..`) to confirm the behavior before running them via SCDF. If it works standalone, it should also work in SCDF.

Comment: Thanks. If I want this behaviour to be the default, is it possible to add it as an environment variable for the dataflow-server container (i.e. `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=application/json`) in the docker-compose setup?

Comment: Did you try the apps locally? Ignore SCDF, Docker and other things for the time being. If you override the property independently in each app and run it as `java -jar`, does it work as expected? Let's make sure the apps work for your need.

Comment: One other thing. SInce you've RabbitMQ as source and sink, you would use a different label to deploy the stream. Likewise, you _need_ to use the label when overriding the property at the deployment time. That would be: `app. rabbitSource.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType='application/json'` in your case. More details in the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_application_properties).

Comment: Have you tried starting both the apps individually via `java -jar rabbit-source.jar --pring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType='application/json'` and `java -jar rabbit-sink.jar --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType='application/json'` for the source and sink apps respectively? When they start and running, do you see these proeprty overrides populated corrrectly through the actuiator endpoints of the applications?

Comment: `curl -c cookies -d "username=user&password=spring_auto_generated_pwd" localhost:8080/actuator/configprop` returns nothing.

Comment: Not all actuator endpoints are exposed by default in Spring Boot 2.1 and over. You need to explicitly enable all via `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` and with that, you should hit http://localhost:8080/actuator/configprops (you had a typo ^^) to verify the property overrides.

Comment: This discussion in comments is not very easy to grok; perhaps you could join one of our gitter channels to continue discussion there instead.